# I can't select updates in Update Manager

Tags: 11.10, upgrade, updates, software-center, update-manager

[image: Unable to select packages to be updated]

Ubuntu 11.10 is installed, and I have updated my system via Ubuntu Software Centre, and after the update 3 updates remain in the list. But I am unable to select them, the tickboxes cannot be checked and Ubuntu Software Centre gives no error when I try to check.

Also, below it says "**There is no update to be installed**" and even though there seems to be updates **Install Updates** button is unclickable.

What should I do in order to install these updates?

Comment: The bug from Radu Rădeanu is clearly related to http://askubuntu.com/questions/349555/language-selector-gnome-in-precise-can-not-be-checked-for-update, the same packages are involved with a small difference: his bug includes translation updates. I tried sudo apt-get clean, sudo apt-get autoremove and sudo apt-get upgrade, but they didn't work, as in previous answer. "Be patient and wait" could be done only if its not a serious security matter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens when you have dependencies that are not met or are unsatisfied. As @BlueXrider suggested, you should first try installing updates from the terminal. If it doesn't work, then you should just be patient and wait. You should be able to install the updates as soon as the required/dependent packages are up to the required version.

Comment: There are also other people who are in the same situation with me with the same packages, so your answer is the solution: I need to wait till the dependencies are updated.

Answer (score 3):

Open dash/terminal

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Then

```
sudo apt-get clean
```

Then

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Then

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: I already tried these commands (except sudo apt-get clean & sudo apt-get autoremove). Now, I tried those two and no change. I guess the problem is related to packages as @Swarnendu Biswas suggests and I need to wait. Thank you for helping.