# language-selector-gnome in Precise can not be checked for update

Tags: 12.04, updates

I tried to update the system (Ubuntu 12.04 LTS "precise") with the Update Manager.  It shows 2 *important security updates* for language-selector-common (0.79.4) and language-selector-gnome (0.79.4), but they can't be selected.  They should be, as any package in Update Manager and as I had done a lot of times.

I check in Synaptic and found the two packages marked with an ! symbol in gray; I don't know what it means.  The installed version is 0.79, for both packages.  I mark them for update, and Synaptic asks to mark for delete language-selector-gnome, ubuntu-desktop and ubuntu-standard.  I don't know if I should delete them or do something different.

- If I try to update language-selector-gnome first, it asks to delete ubuntu-desktop.
- If I try to apply the changes, Synaptics shows a message saying that it can not update because it has language-selector-commons as an unsolvable dependency (it needs language-selector-common 0.79.4).

What should I do?  Leave it without updating?  If update, which would be the correct order in the process? ("first delete this package, then update the other, then reinstall a third" or something like that).  Is the bug in Update Manager, instead?

I guess it has something serious; I've checked the changes report in the un-checkable update and it shows:

"SECURITY UPDATE: possible privilege escalation via policykit UID lookup race.
- dbus_backend/ls-dbus-backend: pass system-bus-name as a subject instead of pid so policykit can get the information from the system bus."

It is confirmed in the National Vulnerability Database (linked from CVE-2013-1066), it links also to a bug for the update (0.79.4), not for the package to be updated (0.79):

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/language-selector/0.79.4

So even the update should be reviewed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I post this also in Launchpad with 2 images: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/language-selector/+bug/1233374

Comment: Did you really read the answer? It says either "update using the terminal" or "wait until the dependencies are correct". I don't see how it doesn't answer your questions.